# Using web.config, httpRedirect entire site to new URL, except one directory

Tags: iis, web-config

I'm moving a site from one server to another. The original server is IIS.  I need to redirect everything from www.old.com to www.new.com, EXCEPT one directory.  I need www.old.com/folder1/folder2 to stay put and still be accessable.   Anyone have any pointers?

This is what I'm using now, but the entire site gets redirected.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <configuration>
     <system.webServer>
       <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://www.new.com/" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" exactDestination="true" />
     </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Then try to use a location tag to disable redirection for that folder.

Comment: Can you provide an example?  I'm an Apache guy and have never worked with web.config.  I do appreciate any help anyone can provide.